# Sequelize MSSQL - Does not return metadata and results

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I am running a raw query like the below on an MSSQL database:

```
sequelize.query(DELETE FROM vehicle where vehicleId IN ('1', '2', '3'))
```

The return is always `[ [], [] ]`. This should contain the metadata and an array result. We also have a MYSQL database with the same tables. When the same query is ran in there, the results come with the expected metadata and results.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html), if I include `{ type: sequelize.QueryTypes.DELETE}` as the second parameter, it would return only the results without the metadata. Instead, it returns `undefined`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: are you sure that your query doesn't have double quotes on it? like sequelize.query("SELECT FROM vehicle where vehicleId IN ('1', '2', '3')"). by the way use spread after seq.query().spread to get the results and metadata

Comment: It has the double quotes in the actual code. Also tried spread but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for those looking to find an answer to this same or a similar concern, I made this work by adding `OUTPUT DELETED.id, DELETED.createdOn, ... WHERE <where clause>`. This also works for inserts. You only need to replace `DELETED` with `INSERTED`. For more details, please refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql).

PS: Erroneously indicated `SELECT` instead of `DELETE` on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by appending a SELECT statement after the INSERT statement. For my particular issue, I had the following:

```
sequelize.query('INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Email, Pwd) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name, @email, @password)')
```

I updated this to

```
sequelize.query('INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Email, Pwd) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name, @email, @password) SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, UserID FROM Users WHERE Email = @email')
```

For clarity, here's the full SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Email, Pwd)
VALUES (@first_name, @last_name, @email, @password)
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, UserID
FROM Users
WHERE Email = @email
```

It's basically two queries. This will return the inserted data without needing to use the OUTPUT clause.

Comment: Please provide additional information, some of us might not fully understand this answer.